# WPF client login without WebBrowser

Tags: identityserver4

I have an angular web site that uses IdentityServer and this seems to work fine. The site is backed by an API. I also need to have a windows wpf application that will allow users to login with the same creds and then talk to the same api.

I can see WPF samples that do this but they use a web browser and a HttpListener for responses.  I would rather not do this!

This is as far as I got:

```
  var disco = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync(_options.IdentityUrl);
  if (!disco.IsError)
  {
    //var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, "client.web", "secret");

    var client = new HttpClient();

    var passwordRequest = new PasswordTokenRequest
    {
      Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,
      GrantType = GrantTypes.Password,

      ClientId = "client.web",
      ClientCredentialStyle = ClientCredentialStyle.PostBody,

      UserName = request.Email,
      Password = SecureStringToString(request.Password)
    };

    var response = await client.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(passwordRequest);
  }
```

I added password to the allowed grant types.

The response is invalid_client.

Anyone done this?

Comment: It seems you haven’t set client secret. Probably that’s the problem.

Comment: Well, I was hoping the username and password would work :)

Comment: Oh, I get it now.  Thats not gonna work.  I'll use the webbrowser control.